# integrate (sdkbox)facebook sdk to game on cocos2dx v3.9

Tags: android, c++, facebook, cocos2d-x

Could You help me please?
 I want to add facebook sdk to my game.
So I use  [sdkbox](http://www.sdkbox.com/plugins/facebook)
After install, I follow the Tutorials :

[Create facebook app](http://blog.cocos2d-x.org/2015/08/getting-started-with-the-sdkbox-facebook-plugin/)
and

[sdk box tutorial](http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/facebook/v3-cpp/),

So, I Write simple code 
In AppDelegate.cpp

```
#ifdef SDKBOX_ENABLED
#include "PluginFacebook/PluginFacebook.h"
#endif
```

and

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // initialize director

#ifdef SDKBOX_ENABLED
    sdkbox::PluginFacebook::init();
#endif
```

and in HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
   if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto rootNode = CSLoader::createNode("MainScene.csb");
    auto btn = static_cast<cocos2d::ui::Button *>(rootNode->getChildByName("Button"));
    btn->addTouchEventListener([this](Ref* pSender, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType type) {
        if (type == cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED)
        {
            cocos2d::MessageBox("test", "test");
#ifdef SDKBOX_ENABLED
            sdkbox::FBShareInfo info;
            info.type = sdkbox::FB_LINK;
            info.link = "https://example.com";
            info.title = "title";
            info.text = "Text";
            info.image = "image;
#endif
        }
    });
    addChild(rootNode);
```

when I click on button , I see MessageBox but after that nothing happen.
I don't publish my app on google play, when i check adb logcat I see only one error

`E/Facebook( 3915): Facebook don't support 'setAppURLSchemeSuffix' on android`

rest seems error
What I do wrong? Thank you for any idea !

Answer (score 1):

'setAppURLSchemeSuffix' is needed only for ios. In sdkbox_config.json file, under "Android section" remove "url_scheme_suffix"

```
"Facebook": {
            "debug": true, 
            "url_scheme_suffix": "",
            "app_id": "251569071901419"
        },
```

This might solve your issue.